# How to prove $|f(x)| \leq C \epsilon |x|^N$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

Suppose that $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d)$ and $D^{\alpha}f(0)=0$ for all $0\leq |\alpha|\leq N.$ We may assume that
$$|D^{\alpha}f(x)| \leq \epsilon \quad \text{for all} \quad |\alpha|=N$$
in small neighbourhood of origin.

Question: How to show that

$$|f(x)| \leq C \epsilon |x|^N$$
?

My thought: Maybe I've to invoke mean value theorem.  But I do not know how when $N\neq 1.$

**Edit**: Notation: $D^{\alpha}= \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial x_N^{\alpha_N}},  \quad |\alpha|= \alpha_1+ \cdots + \alpha_n, \alpha_i \in \mathbb N_0$

Comment: Have you tried to see what happen if $d=1$ ? And $|D^\alpha f(x)|\leq \varepsilon $ for all $x\in \mathbb R^d$ ? I guess using Taylor polynomial should be the key.

Comment: What are $D$, $D^\alpha$? It seems to be a derivative and an index but if so why $|\alpha|$, why $0\leq\alpha$ which don't make sense for an index.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: thanks. I've edited noation

Comment: @Surb: Thanks it is valid in a small neighbourhood of origin. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Surb: Also,  Please can you elaborate how to use Taylor expansion

Comment: This is false as stated, unless you want to show your inequality also in a small neighborhood of the origin?

Comment: @LL3.14: Yes, in the small neighbourhood of origin.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in\Bbb R^d$ and $u(t) := f(tx)$. It follows from the one dimensional Taylor formula that for any $t\in\Bbb R$ and
$$
f(tx) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{u^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \,t^n + \int_0^t \frac{u^{(N)}(s)}{(N-1)!}\,(t-s)^{N-1}\,\mathrm d s
$$
Since $u^{(n)}(t) = \sum_{|\alpha|=n}x^{\alpha} D^\alpha f(tx)$, we get that $u^{(n)}(0) = 0$, so the sum vanishes, and so taking $t=1$ yields
$$
f(x) = \sum_{|\alpha|=N}x^{\alpha}\int_0^1 \frac{D^\alpha f(sx)}{(N-1)!}\,(1-s)^{N-1}\,\mathrm d s
$$
In particular, if for all $s\in[0,1]$, $sx$ is in the small neigborhood of the origin where the gradient is smaller than $\varepsilon$, then
$$
|f(x)| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{(N-1)!} \sum_{|\alpha|=N}|x|^N\int_0^1 \,(1-s)^{N-1}\,\mathrm d s =  \tfrac{(d+N-1)!}{(N!)^2\,(d-1)!}\,\varepsilon\,|x|^N.
$$